# Lubuntu 20.04 - logon screen - where is "other user" option?

Tags: lubuntu, login

I'm not able to login with domain users.
I put my Lubuntu 20.04 at domain and the machine appears at computers list domain, domain users can login by ssh, but there is no option to login domain users by GUI. I suppost should have the "other user" option to type user, domain and password.

Comment: `sddm` processes local logins only, the logins need to be pre-setup, as they are read from existing accounts.  I'd suggest using normal POSIX commands to create new accounts (over the GUI tools).

Comment: workaround was change the login theme for another that has the other user option.